# Cannot implicitly Convert Type (C# and Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Following a tutorial that is teaching how to build a sudoku solver. Created two files, SudokuMap.cs which is the data folder and SudokuMapper.cs that contained in the Workers folder. SudokuMapper.cs is suppose to map the row and column within the 9 by 9 grid.

The follow error is occurs next to the return statement in 'SudokuMapper.cs'.

[image]

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'SudokuSolver.Data.SudokuMap' to 'SudoSolver.Workers.SudokuMapper'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? I doubled checked the final version of the code and everything is exactly the same.

Here is the code for context.

SudokuMapper.cs

```
using SudokuSolver.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SudokuSolver.Workers
{
    class SudokuMapper
    {
        public SudokuMapper Find(int givenRow, int givenCol)
        {
            SudokuMap sudokuMap = new SudokuMap();

            if ((givenRow >= 0 && givenRow <= 2) && (givenCol >= 0 && givenCol <= 2))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 0;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 0;
            }

            else if ((givenRow >= 0 && givenRow <= 2) && (givenCol >= 3 && givenCol <= 5))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 0;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 3;
            }

            else if ((givenRow >= 0 && givenRow <= 2) && (givenCol >= 6 && givenCol <= 8))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 0;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 6;
            }


            if ((givenRow >= 3 && givenRow <= 5) && (givenCol >= 0 && givenCol <= 2))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 3;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 0;
            }

            if ((givenRow >= 3 && givenRow <= 5) && (givenCol >= 3 && givenCol <= 5))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 3;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 3;
            }

            if ((givenRow >= 3 && givenRow <= 5) && (givenCol >= 6 && givenCol <= 8))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 3;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 6;
            }

            if ((givenRow >= 6 && givenRow <= 8) && (givenCol >= 0 && givenCol <= 2))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 6;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 0;
            }

            if ((givenRow >= 6 && givenRow <= 8) && (givenCol >= 3 && givenCol <= 5))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 6;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 3;
            }

            if ((givenRow >= 6 && givenRow <= 8) && (givenCol >= 6 && givenCol <= 8))
            {
                sudokuMap.StartRow = 6;
                sudokuMap.StartCol = 6;
            }
            return sudokuMap;
        }
    }
}
```

SudokuMap.cs

```
namespace SudokuSolver.Data
{
    class SudokuMap
    {
        public int StartRow { get; set; }
        public int StartCol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SudokuMapper` and `SudokuMap` are not the same. Check your return type. The tutorial may have done it wrong, but take a closer look just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. Your `Find` method is written to return `SudokuMapper`, not `SudokuMap`.

Change this line here:

```cs
public SudokuMapper Find(int givenRow, int givenCol)
```

To:

```cs
public SudokuMap Find(int givenRow, int givenCol)
```

IMO, this error message is confusing. You get this because the compiler is looking for a way to cast `SodukuMap` to `SodukuMapper` and can't find one. It should probably include something along the lines of "Expected return type X, got Y".